# IIS7 Re-Write a .axd extension to different extension

Tags: url, iis-7, url-rewriting, axd

I have an e-commerce application that using a .axd handler for the page extensions.

I simply want to use IIS7 to create a rule that says .shop = .axd

Can this be done?  If so how should I go about it?

Thanks

Comment: You might consider marking my answer as accepted, if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to add a handler mapping to your web application.

Specifically, you should add a new [Module Mapping](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/121/iis-7-modules-overview/):

[image: Add a Module Mapping in IIS7]